# Limits in motion

Tags: limits

Consider points $A=(−10,−4)$ and $C=(8,5)$. The point $B$ is on the line passing through $A$ and $C$. The $x$-coordinate of $B$ is $−1$. 
Determine the $y$-coordinate of the point $B$.

*Hint:* Do not figure out the equation of the line to solve this problem. Instead, use similar triangles to discover the equation of a line for yourself.

Please explain how to solve this. Also, kindly explain how is it done using limits or its connection to limits in motion.

Comment: **Hint:** Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried AB + BC = AC. Couldn't compute it fully. But I don't understand how it is related to limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would see this, my answer, is like similar triangles using ratios. Find the proportion of the distance that the $x$ coordinate of $B$ minus that of $A$ is to the difference of $x$ coord's of $A$ and $C$ say in the order that of $C$ minus $A$ then multiply that by the difference in $y$ coord's of $A$ and $C$ in same order that of $C$ minus that of $A$ and add it to the $y$ coord. of $A$ since I took the $x$ coord. of point $A$ as the reference. Get 
-4+(-1-(-10) )/(8-(-10))*(5-(-4))=-4+9/18*9 = 1/2 = 0.5 as the $y$ coordinate of point B

Answer (score 0):

Well $B$ is in the middle, as

$$
-10 \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{+9} -1 \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{+9} 8
$$

So we have to solve

$$
-4 \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{?} ? \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{?} 5
$$

which is

$$
-4 \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{4\tfrac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\longrightarrow\longrightarrow}_{4\tfrac{1}{2}} 5
$$

Comment: Thank you. How would you answer the same question if it wasn't midpoint?

Comment: They would have the same ratios.

Say we have

$$ +6 / +12 $$

We get

$$ +3 / +6$$

Answer (score 0):

Relation with Limits:One thing that seems apparent is that since B lies right at the average of the x values of the triangles, then the triangles should be congruent. Therefore the y value of B should be the average of A and C y values. 1/2 And if you see other two questions in coursera you see the shift of y-coordinate of pointB as x-coordinate changes